# Spark on K8s - getting error: kube mode not support referencing app depenpendcies in local

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I am trying to setup a spark cluster on k8s. I've managed to create and setup a cluster with three nodes by following this article: 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/

After that when I tried to deploy spark on the cluster it failed at spark submit setup. 
I used this command:

```
~/opt/spark/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit \
--master k8s://https://206.189.126.172:6443 \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--name word-count \
--class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
--conf spark.executor.instances=5 \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=docker.io/garfiny/spark:v2.3.0 \
—-conf spark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name=word-count \
local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar
```

And it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: The Kubernetes mode does not yet support referencing application dependencies in the local file system.
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.DriverConfigOrchestrator.getAllConfigurationSteps(DriverConfigOrchestrator.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication$$anonfun$run$5.apply(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication$$anonfun$run$5.apply(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:2585)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.run(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.start(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:879)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

2018-06-04 10:58:24 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Shutdown hook called
2018-06-04 10:58:24 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory /private/var/folders/lz/0bb8xlyd247cwc3kvh6pmrz00000gn/T/spark-3967f4ae-e8b3-428d-ba22-580fc9c840cd

Note: I followed this article for installing spark on k8s.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message comes from [commit 5d7c4ba4d73a72f26d591108db3c20b4a6c84f3f](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/5d7c4ba4d73a72f26d591108db3c20b4a6c84f3f) and include the page you mention: "[Running Spark on Kubernetes](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#dependency-management)" with the mention that you indicate:

```scala
// TODO(SPARK-23153): remove once submission client local dependencies are supported.
if (existSubmissionLocalFiles(sparkJars) || existSubmissionLocalFiles(sparkFiles)) {
  throw new SparkException("The Kubernetes mode does not yet support referencing application " +
    "dependencies in the local file system.")
}
```

This is described in [SPARK-18278](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18278):

> it wouldn't accept running a local: jar file, e.g. `local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.2.0-k8s-0.5.0.jar`, on my spark docker image (`allowsMixedArguments` and `isAppResourceReq booleans` in `SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java` get in the way).

And this is linked to [kubernetes issue 34377](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/34377)

The [issue SPARK-22962 "Kubernetes app fails if local files are used"](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22962) mentions:

> This is the resource staging server use-case. We'll upstream this in the 2.4.0 timeframe.

In the meantime, that error message was introduced in [PR 20320](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/20320).

It includes the comment:

> The manual tests I did actually use a main app jar located on gcs and http.
>   To be specific and for record, I did the following tests:
>
> - Using a gs:// main application jar and a http:// dependency jar. Succeeded.
> - Using a https:// main application jar and a http:// dependency jar. Succeeded.
> - Using a local:// main application jar. Succeeded.
> - Using a file:// main application jar. Failed.
> - Using a file:// dependency jar. Failed.

That issue should been fixed by now, and the [OP garfiny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714376/garfiny) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50637250/spark-on-k8s-getting-error-kube-mode-not-support-referencing-app-depenpendcie/50673683?noredirect=1#comment88396515_50673683):

> I used the newest `spark-kubernetes jar` to replace the one in `spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7` package. The exception is gone.

Comment: Thanks VonC. I used the newest spark-kubernetes jar to replace the one in spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7 package. The exception is gone. But there is still other problems I need to solve. I'll post the final testing result once I make everything works.

Answer (score 2):

According to the mentioned [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#dependency-management):

> #### Dependency Management
>
> If your application’s dependencies are all
> hosted in remote locations like HDFS or HTTP servers, they may be
> referred to by their appropriate remote URIs. **Also, application
> dependencies can be pre-mounted into custom-built Docker images.** Those
> dependencies can be added to the classpath by referencing them with
> local:// URIs and/or setting the SPARK_EXTRA_CLASSPATH environment
> variable in your Dockerfiles. **The local:// scheme is also required
> when referring to dependencies in custom-built Docker images in
> spark-submit**.
>
> Note that using application dependencies **from the
> submission client’s local file system is currently not yet supported.**