# Where to place the Spark application while spark-submitting it to Kubernetes?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kubernetes, spark-submit

I have the same case as in this topic. [Spark on K8s - getting error: kube mode not support referencing app depenpendcies in local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50637250/spark-on-k8s-getting-error-kube-mode-not-support-referencing-app-depenpendcie/)

I run Spark from a container. https://github.com/gettyimages/docker-spark/blob/master/Dockerfile

```
bin/spark-submit \
--master k8s://https://kubernetes:6443 \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--name spark-pi \
--class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
--conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=spark \
--conf spark.executor.instances=5 \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=gcr.io/cloud-solutions-images/spark:v2.3.0-gcs \
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.caCertFile=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/k8.crt \
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \ 
local:///usr/spark-2.3.0/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: The Kubernetes mode does not yet support referencing application dependencies in the local file system.
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.DriverConfigOrchestrator.getAllConfigurationSteps(DriverConfigOrchestrator.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication$$anonfun$run$5.apply(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:229)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication$$anonfun$run$5.apply(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:227)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:2585)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.run(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:227)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.start(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:879)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
2018-07-07 05:56:27 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Shutdown hook called
2018-07-07 05:56:27 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory /tmp/spark-67367f1a-4ea8-43d6-98e4-23bd6015c6a6
```

The possible solution there is not fully demonstrated.

I do not know what to do? How to fix? Spark version 2.3.0.

I tried to download a new version of the spark-kubernetes jar in spark/jars.

Copied and renamed spark-kubernetes_2.11-2.3.1.jar -> spark-kubernetes_2.11-2.3.0.jar.

After this fix Spark does not find the corresponding kubernetes files.

Comment: What's wrong with copying the jar into hdfs or s3 or an http server until that behavior changes?

Comment: I did not understand you a little. What do you mean?

Comment: My background with Spark is inside a Hadoop cluster, where one had to copy the jar into HDFS or S3 and then submit the job that ran the network accessible jar location. The bug(?) you linked to also mentioned http URLs would work, too, if using HDFS or S3 was too inconvenient. Basically replace `local://opt/` with `s3://some-bucket` and use that instead of waiting for the next release

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel thansk for the answer.

I copied the spark to hdfs, but I get the same error.

root@ca-spark-deployment-64bbfb4cfb-lnsdh:/usr/spark-2.3.1# hadoop fs -put /usr/spark-2.3.1/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.1.jar /tmp/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.1.jar

Comment: same error what, as I would not expect a "local file system" error when giving it an HDFS jar path?

Comment: I think I'm doing something wrong or do not understand what hdfs is.
I use this container : https://hub.docker.com/r/gettyimages/spark/~/dockerfile/ .

and when I look through eg hdfs dfs -ls / - then it shows me just the root folders of the system. And if I copy the file to / tmp, then tmp is in my real system. Therefore, the same error occurs.

Comment: Then maybe tag this question with `hadoop` or `hdfs` or open a new question, because that problem has nothing to do with kubernetes (or spark, for that matter)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

this is command that worked for me:

```
/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit \
--class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
--master k8s://https://$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST:$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT \
--conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=myproject \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--conf spark.app.name=my-spark-app \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=jkremser/openshift-spark:2.3-latest \
--conf spark.kubernetes.submission.waitAppCompletion=false \
--conf spark.kubernetes.driver.label.radanalytics.io/app=my-spark-app \
--conf spark.driver.cores=0.100000 \
--conf spark.kubernetes.driver.limit.cores=200m \
--conf spark.driver.memory=512m \
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark-operator \
--conf spark.kubernetes.driver.label.version=2.3.0 \
--conf spark.kubernetes.executor.label.sparkoperator.k8s.io/app-name=my-spark-app \
--conf spark.executor.instances=1 \
--conf spark.executor.cores=1 \
--conf spark.executor.memory=512m \
--conf spark.kubernetes.executor.label.version=2.3.0 \
--conf spark.jars.ivy=/tmp/.ivy2 \
local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar
```

Make sure the `/usr/spark-2.3.0/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar` file is present in the container image (`gcr.io/cloud-solutions-images/spark:v2.3.0-gcs` in your case), because it shouldn't point to the local file, but to a file in the container.

You can do that by something like:

```
docker run --rm -ti gcr.io/cloud-solutions-images/spark:v2.3.0-gcs sh
```

and inspect what's there (where is the jar with the examples).

Good luck.